# css styles not working if php file is target in <a href>

Tags: html, css

If target file is .php none of the formatting for the tag will be applied. Only if the tag is for a .html or .htm will the formatting apply. The link works either way and the .php file is loaded.

`<a href="/contact/index.html"> Email2</a>`
tag formatted properly from css file

`<a href="/contact/index.php"> Email2</a>`
no format applied

tags applied:

`a {
  color: #cccccc;
  }`

`a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
  }`

Hope I am doing this right:
Here is the fiddle page of all the html and css
you will see that the formatting is done on the .html but not on the .php
Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/96fcapmw/

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) where we can see this ?

Comment: if you put the code you posted into a snippet or jsfiddle, both links work/look the same way on hover

Comment: Works in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fmozykvg/

Must be something else in your markup causing it.

Comment: added the fiddle , at the bottom of the page is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, your CSS ends like this:

```
.footer a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer a:visited {
  color: #fff;

}
```

But that way, the `a:visited` style will always overwrite the `a:hover` style as soon as you have clicked that link once, just because of the *order* of those to rules. (the second always overwrites the first one, if it has been visited once)

To avoid that, just turn the order around:

```
.footer a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here it's done that way in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntfx5xws/1/